# Monetizando app android

Tags: android

Bom dia! Quero colocar um app na play store por 99 cents. Como vou receber o dinheiro por cada download de aplicativo?

Li algo sobre o google wallet mas nao consigo baixar o aplicativo no Brasil...

Como funciona?

Comment: Acredito que o google wallet não é um app, é uma conta que precisa fazer em seu nome para receber o dinheiro proveniente das vendas do aplicativo. Lembrando que o google cobra uma taxa de 30%, logo irá receber 0.70 cents por download. A conta no google wallet pode ser feita aqui: https://wallet.google.com/manage